# Updating multiple values in Array in MongoDB using C

Tags: c, mongodb

I want to update multiple values in mongodb Array using `$each` modifier and i am trying to do it like this

```
bson_init( b );
            bson_append_start_object(b,"$addToSet");
            bson_append_start_object(b,"$each");
            bson_append_string(b,"grades","12");
            bson_append_string(b,"grades","Temp");
            bson_append_finish_object(b);
            bson_append_finish_object(b);
bson_finish(b );
```

But not getting success, but when i am trying to add only one item then its working like this

```
   bson_init( b );
                bson_append_start_object(b,"$addToSet");
                bson_append_string(b,"grades","Temp");
                bson_append_finish_object(b);
    bson_finish(b );
```

Can anyone guide me how i can do this. I am using C Driver.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to encapsulate the list of objects for $each using "bson_append_start_array", which is used to represent the array representation that the $each would work on.

I would suggest writing a mongo update statement and then converting to an appropriate 'C' representation.